# missing argument when using importlib to create a class at runtime

Tags: python, self, python-importlib

I want to load a Python file (module) dynamically when the user inputs the filename (here for example: `RegionOfInterest.py`). In the file will be one class (here: `RegionOfInterest`). All classes have a method with the same name (here: `start`) which I want to call.

This works fine, but if I call another method from the start method I get an error:

```
TypeError: testMethod() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Minimal Working Example:

**main.py:**

```py
import importlib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    module_name = "RegionOfInterest"    # will be user input
    class_name = module_name            # same as module_name

    myModule = importlib.import_module(f"{module_name}")
    myClass = myModule.__getattribute__(class_name)
    myClass.__init__(myClass)           # apparently is not called automatically ?
    myMethod = myClass.__getattribute__(myClass, "start")
    myMethod(myClass)
```

**RegionOfInterest.py:**

```py
class RegionOfInterest:

    def start(self):
        self.testMethod()

    def testMethod(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this code:

```py
myClass.__init__(myClass, img)
myMethod = myClass.__getattribute__(myClass, "start")
myMethod(myClass)
```

`myClass` is a class, not an instance of that class. So your passing an invalid object as `self` to the `__init__()` method.

The following seems much simpler to me and does work without the error:

```py
import importlib

module_name = 'RegionOfInterest'
class_name = module_name

module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
Class = getattr(module, class_name)
obj = Class()
obj.start()
```

NB: I replaced [`object.__getattribute__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) by [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), although I think both should work for your specific situation. I also changed the naming to follow PEP-8.

Comment: Thank you. The way I did it, the instance had no "self" to pass to a subroutine, if that makes sense. :)

Comment: `myModule.__getattribute__(class_name)` should really be `getattr(myModule, class_name)`. The `__getattribute__` magic method is only part of the protocol to get attributes, in general you shouldn't call that directly.

Comment: @Jasmijn, "_in general you shouldn't call that directly_". Do you have any reference for that? I couldn't find any, and both functions are explicitly documented (i.e. they are not some "internal use" methods that are likely to change in future). It's not really relevant for this question (the problem is in how the class is used, not in how it is acquired), but I _do_ prefer answers that apply good programming practices. I've updated the code in my answer for sake of argument (`getattr` looks nicer anyway), but if there's a real good reason to avoid the alternative, I would like to hear it.

Comment: @wovano I don't have a reference, but there is a reason: if the class implements a `__getattr__` fallback, using `__getattribute__` will miss dynamic attributes. Other dunder methods may have similar caveats. Dunder methods are documented and are not internal use, but they are used for implementing the nuts and bolts of the data model, and there are generally better ways to interface with them. In my own code, as a rule any dunder method should be either preceded by `def` or by `super().`, and other code uses the interface: `getattr`, `len`, `iter`, `next`, `+`, indexing, etc.

Comment: @Jasmijn, thanks for the explanation. That's what I figured and I generally agree with this train of thought. In this case, however, `__getattribute__` was used on a module, and I don't expect that `__getattribute__` would fail to return a class from the module and implement a `__getattr__` method. But it won't hurt to use `getattr()` either, so I think it's an improvement. So thanks for your comments.